# mr.MapredLocalTask (MapredLocalTask.java:executeInChildVM(351))

Tags: hadoop, hive

2017-09-04 16:50:23,882 INFO  [main]: mr.MapredLocalTask (MapredLocalTask.java:executeInChildVM(172)) - Generating plan file file:/tmp/admin/1a83c312-332f-4f0a-a401-40356747d414/hive_2017-09-04_16-50-22_972_3396311132793676844-1/-local-10004/plan.xml
2017-09-04 16:50:24,248 INFO  [main]: mr.MapredLocalTask (MapredLocalTask.java:executeInChildVM(319)) - Executing: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.12.0-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.29/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.12.0-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.29/jars/hive-exec-1.1.0-cdh5.12.0.jar org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver -localtask -plan file:/tmp/admin/1a83c312-332f-4f0a-a401-40356747d414/hive_2017-09-04_16-50-22_972_3396311132793676844-1/-local-10004/plan.xml   -jobconffile file:/tmp/admin/1a83c312-332f-4f0a-a401-40356747d414/hive_2017-09-04_16-50-22_972_3396311132793676844-1/-local-10005/jobconf.xml
2017-09-04 16:50:24,254 ERROR [main]: mr.MapredLocalTask (MapredLocalTask.java:executeInChildVM(351)) - Exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask.executeInChildVM(MapredLocalTask.java:326)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask.execute(MapredLocalTask.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:99)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2041)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1748)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1501)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1275)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:383)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:318)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:720)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:693)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:628)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Comment: Your question doesn't specify anything. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: CDH  vertion: 5.12.0. When use 'left join' ,the problem happening

Comment: i am using the same CDH version and having the same problem, please tell me if you find a solution to this, thanku

Answer (score 0):

I can run some of my queries by setting:

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=false
```

or

```
set hive.exec.submit.local.task.via.child=false
```

Hope it will solve yr problem.